# What will happen if heap memory gets full?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

1. What will happen in below case?
2. What will happen if I write `if (p == NULL) { break; }`?

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>  
   void main()  
   {  
       int *p;  
       while (1)  
       {  
           p = malloc(1024); // allocating memory in infinite while loop  
           // if (p == NULL) { break; }
       }  
   }
   ```

Comment: If malloc returned null, and you dereference null, you get a segmentation fault or undefined behavior.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Do you mean: `if(p==NULL){ break; }` ?

Comment: 1. you probably mean `if (p == NULL)` (or simply `if (!p)`). 2. [man malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) should be enough to answer this question.

Comment: We expect [so] users to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking.

Comment: What i am asking is what happens if heap memory gets full. by mistake i wrote *p.

Comment: I tried in my PC. Its not giving any error. but my PC got hang.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: It's not that obvious, especially on platforms which don't give you the memory until you actually use it.

Comment: @Bathsheba even then, the runtime must allocate SOME memory for a valid pointer to return ... so it might just take (much) longer.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: That's a question in itself. I can't see why a compiler cannot model a machine with infinite memory; the "as-if" rule would still apply, but alas I'm far from being an expert in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What will happen in below case?

Your heap will get full. When this happens, `malloc()` won't be able to allocate memory anymore and it's going to return `NULL` pointers indefinitely.

> What will happen if I write `if (p == NULL) { break; }`?

Your heap will get full. But here, your program will exit, since you're breaking out of the `while` loop in case `malloc()` fails to allocate memory.

Comment: In 1st case it will return null. but i have not used if(p==NULL){break;}. So it wont exit the loop. So what happens in memory?

Comment: @UtkarshPatel Even though you keep on calling `malloc()`, it won't be able to allocate. Instead, it will return a `NULL` pointer each time it is called. So as Felix said, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

1. You might expect to run out of memory eventually, and `malloc` must return `NULL` in that case. But note that some C runtime libraries and operating systems will not actually allocate the memory until you use it. Since you're not using the memory, you might find that the loops runs forever, but not due to the explicit failure of `malloc`.
2. Inclusion of the `if` statement will end the program if `malloc` fails to allocate. If the C runtime libary and operating system are behaving in the way I've mentioned, then `malloc` may well never fail to allocate and your program *could* loop infinitely *despite* the `if` conditional.